# How to determine if AWS user/arn doesn't have console/admin permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, multi-factor-authentication

We have some "bots" on AWS - we don't require MFA for these bots - but we sure as hell don't want them to have high-level access on AWS. I believe there is some permission to give users access to the website/console. My question is - if you were me, what permissions would you check to make sure our bots who aren't required to have MFA don't get access privileges above their pay grade?

For example, one of our bot users has a policy like so:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:HeadBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::interos-oregon",
                "arn:aws:s3:::*/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The console doesn't automatically give you access to everything. User accounts have access to resources based on their, or their groups', policy. If the "bot" with the policy above had a password, that "bot" could effect s3 exactly as given by that policy through the console. So when you say "high-level access on AWS", do you mean the root user? If so, that user has the `AdministratorAccess` policy, which you probably don't want your "bots" having: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_job-functions.html

Comment: See also https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/getting-started_create-admin-group.html

Comment: The policy you have provided grants the bot the ability to do **anything it wants in Amazon S3** in your AWS account. That's probably "above its pay grade".

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for granting privileges is the principal of “least access”. Users, functions, and/or bots, should only be permitted to assume roles that have the bare minimum permissions that they need to accomplish their task.

In addition to this you should regularly review IAM roles, policies, and access to confirm that user, functions, bots, or whatever has only the necessary permissions.

You can read more about IAM best practices [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html).